# Invalid type code:19 when changing JDK version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, java-14

So I want to use var keyword in Android studio. So I download the latest JDK and changed my project to point to it:

[image]

Now when I sync I get this error:

> 12:37 PM  Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid type code: 19
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (684 ms)

my Android gradle plugin version is 4.0.1 and Gradle version is 6.1.1

EDIT: I think maybe Android Studio only supports up to JDK 8: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: I think you cannot use JDK 14 yet in Android Studio. However, have you tried the following in your gradle file? 


compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

Comment: Didn't work: "Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid type code: FE"

I think maybe Android studio only supports up to Java 8 which means I don't think I can use "var" which was jdk 10.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem, that Gradle 6.0 (and 6.1) does not support JDK 14. Only JDK 13 and older are supported.

https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html#support-for-java-13
https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/release-notes.html#upgrade-instructions